# How to get information from console

Tags: javascript, eclipse, error-handling, console

I am developing an app using Java and Javascript and I have an email service that the user can send an automatic email to me if an error occurs with the application. I have it sending a blank email to me at the moment but I would like it to get the error message from the console and paste it into the email. I have to code to add it to the email but how do I get the information from the console?

EDIT:

```
2012-05-03 10:20:46,449 [mobileapp] DEBUG Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2012-05-03 10:20:46,449 [mobileapp] WARN  Request method 'GET' not supported
2012-05-03 10:20:46,449 [mobileapp] DEBUG Null ModelAndView returned to   DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2012-05-03 10:20:46,449 [mobileapp] TRACE Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@741848
```

Comment: Error log and console are different things and there are several different consoles in Eclipse. Perhaps you want to be more specific, which one you want to "read" from.

Comment: i am using log4j properties to print out what is going on in the log console so whenever i get an error it is printed out on the console like in the edit added, if i could save that as a string or something similar so i could add it to the email

Comment: do you use javascript or java?

Comment: log4j is Java, not JavaScript. If you happen to use JavaScript nevertheless, you could simply hijack whatever logging mechanism you use.

Comment: I have all the server side coded with java so whenever there is an error here i want to send an email with this info, the java is also generating the email. the actual application is coded in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript, there is no "real" console. Instead install a plug-in that provides this for you - e.g. FireBug (for Firefox) or just use Chrome. That has worked for me, when you do a console.log("whatever") it should be shown there.

Good luck!

Comment: U misunderstand my question, i dont want to write to the console, instead i want to take information from the console. Because the server side is coded using java, if an error appears on the server side because of what the application is trying to do, i want the server to get this error from the console and add this to an email that will be sent to me so that i can fix it if the user chooses the option to send a report to me... its all coded except for getting the error from the console

Comment: Ok, well then I way way way off base!

Comment: its ok, i managed to sort this. I added a log4j.properties file to my application and set it up so that it used SMTPAppender so that it would send an error to my email address when ever an ERROR occurred